# Is there a Geonetwork API to create a user

Tags: api, geonetwork

I would like to build a bit of custom code around geonetwork where I want to reuse existing database from gn. For my usecase it would be nice if users could register on a custom site and then use the credentials as their geonetwork login.

Now, instead of reinventing the wheel when writing all the neccessary tables like users, groups, email, etc. it would be helpful to have API access to those functionality.

The closest I found is [this](http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/eng/users/api/the-geonetwork-api.html). So it's likely, something similar exists, but seems to be undocumented.

Does anyone know, how to access user creation functionality as is done when registering on the geonetwork-ui?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API is almost the same as in version 2. You can use the following one:

http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/2.10.4/eng/developer/xml_services/user_xml_services.html#create-a-user-xml-user-update

> The xml.user.update service can be used to create new users, update
>   user information and reset user password, depending on the value of
>   the operation parameter. Only users with profiles Administrator or
>   UserAdmin can create new users.
>
> Users with profile Administrator can create users in any group, while
>   users with profile UserAdmin can create users only in the groups to
>   which they belong.
>
> Requires authentication: Yes